# Is there any open source library for tidy up Javascript using Javascript inside browser?

Tags: javascript, frontend, tidy

Is there any library that I can use to convert code like this:

```
function () {
var a = 1;
}
```

to code like this:

```
function () {
    var a = 1;
}
```

Inside my browser. Because I'm using gh-pages in Github I don't have a back-end so I'm looking only for browser based JavaScript solutions.

Comment: This may help https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This website will do it and has links to lots of plugin for different systems.

http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Thanks It was tricky to work with it (due to lack of documents) but you gave me the correct answer.